# SVAR: Long-run or short restrictions

Tags: vector-autoregression, eviews, restrictions

**TL;DR**

What is the difference between regular and long run SVAR model?

**In details:**

I am estimating a SVAR model, with tourist arrivals, accomodation capacities and consumer confidence.

I am chose the SVAR modelisation because it allows me make contemporaneous interactions between the tourist arrivals and the accomodation capacities ; when the accomodation capacities increase, the arrivals should react immediately. The arrivals should also react immediately when the consumer confidence index (CCI) increases. So, what I have is the following:

**Ae = Bu**

With, **e**, the errors in the reduced form and **u**, the structural shocks. A and B are matrixes with:

A:

(1 a b)

(0 1 0)

(0 0 1)

B:

(c 0 0)

(0 d 0)

(0 0 e)

All a,b,c,d and e are estimated (with Eviews).
Here, a and b (in A) make the contemperounous link between arrivals and the other 2 variables. c,d and e allow to estimate the structural shock.

My question is: ***Eviews allows to make short run restrictions (using A and B matrixes) but also long run restrictions with noly one matrix. What is the difference between both?***